# joomla module configuration field type color

Tags: module, joomla2.5, joomla-module

in my joomla 2.5 module settings i have many color picker fields as follows.for this i showed only one.

```
<config>
<fields name="params">
<fieldset name="module_design" label="design settings">
<field name="fb_color1" type="color" default="#333333" label="backg color" />
.....................other color picker fields not shown here...............
```

there are 20 color picker fields but after 14th color picker field, rest of the color picker fields not showing color picker when mouse clicked on field input box.so first 14 showing but not others !! i tried to move those in another fieldset but no solution.

Edited:
Here are all fields under design fieldset.i did not posted other fieldsets.so problem was color picker was not appearing starting from fb_postandlinksecbordercolor field.now having problem that only first field's color picker showing not others!

```
<fieldset name="module_design_settings" label="wall feeds view design settings">
<field name="fb_postcolor" type="color" default="#333333" label="LABEL_POSTCOLOR"  />
<field name="fb_backcolor" type="color" default="#FFFFFF" label="LABEL_BACKCOLOR"  />
<field name="fb_backcolorcom" type="color" default="#EDEFF4" label="LABEL_BACKCOLORCOMMENTS"  />            
<field name="fb_colorcom" type="color" default="#333333" label="LABEL_COMMENTSCOLOR"  />

<field name="fb_postbordercolor" type="color" default="#F0F0F0" label="LABEL_POSTBORDERCOLOR"  />                       
<field name="fb_linkcolor" type="color" default="#3B5998" label="LABEL_LINKSCOLOR"  />
<field name="fb_datecolor" type="color" default="#777" label="LABEL_DATECOLOR"  />
<field name="fb_postlikebgcolor" type="color" default="#EDEFF4" label="LABEL_LIKESECBKCOLOR"  />
<field name="fb_postlikeseccolor" type="color" default="#333333" label="LABEL_LIKESECTEXTCOLOR"  />
<field name="fb_postlikenumccolor" type="color" default="#3B5998" label="LABEL_LIKESECNUMBERCOLOR"  />
<field name="fb_wallpostcolor" type="color" default="white" label="wall post section background color"  />          
<field name="fb_postandlinkcolor" type="color" default="#333333" label="wall post and link text color"  />
<field name="fb_activepostandlinkcolor" type="color" default="maroon" label="active wall post/link text color"  />  

<field name="fb_postandlinksecbordercolor" type="color" default="#CCCCCC" label="wall post/link section border color"  />           
<field name="fb_postandlinkseccolor" type="color" default="black" label="wall post/link section text color"  />
<field name="fb_postsechintcolor" type="color" default="maroon" label="wall post/link section hint text color"  />
<field name="fb_posttofbbtnsecbackcolor" type="color" default="#f2f2f2" label="'click to write post'/'post' button section background color"  />    
<field name="fb_posttofbbtnbackcolor" type="color" default="#6079AB" label="'click to write post'/'post' button background color"  />   
<field name="fb_posttofbbtncolor" type="color" default="white" label="'click to write post'/'post' button text color"  />           

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check if you have an error in your XML file around the 14th or 15th field.

Comment: What errors you saying? I see no errors  but just the color picker not appearing when i click on the input box of 15th field.

Comment: I really don't know. But from the info you gave, that's all I can guess.
Maybe post the whole config file so we can test it ourself?

Comment: Don't use color names for the default values. Use the hex code.

Comment: oh great man i removed color names like "red" and used code like "#ffffff" and things working well!!.let me check more in server too :)

Answer (score 0):

The broblem is on color code. If you use html code (like #2033b2) it work fine.. when you use a labelled color (like yellow or maroon in your case) the following field don't show color picker. You have to use only html color codes.

I had the same problem and solved with this method.